# Poisson's Kinematical Equation in Index Notation

Tags: rotations, kinematics, index-notation

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to write Poisson's kinematical equation in index notation.  The matrix form is

$[\dot{C}] = -[\omega^\times][C]$

My first try is

$\dot{C}_{jk}=-\epsilon_{ijk}\omega_iC_{jk}$

However, this seems to leave two free indices on the left (which I want) and none on right because $j$ and $k$ are repeated, which means they're summed.  Is there something I can change to make this work like it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just a few missing indices. Note first, that in a product $AB$, the $(i,j)$-entry of the product is 
$$ (AB)_{ij} = A_{ik}B_{kj} $$
Hence, 
$$ [\omega^\times][C]_{jk} = [\omega^\times]_{ji}C_{ik} $$
This gives 
$$ \dot C_{jk} = -\epsilon_{\ell ji}\omega_\ell C_{ik} $$